# What is the recommended way to have two characters speak simultaneously?

Tags: dramatist

### Problem

I have two characters, defined like so:

```
\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}
\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}
```

They speak separately for the entirety of the play when I want them to speak together. I want it to look like this:

> Alice: Are you ready?
>
> Bob: Yes. On three. One…two…
>
> Alice and Bob: Three!

In LaTeX, I so far have this:

```
\alicespeaks Are you ready?

\bobspeaks Yes. On three. One…two…

%How do I get them to say this?: Three!
```

As you can see, I have no idea how to get them to say the following line in unison.

### What I've tried

I see that there is a `CharacterGroup`, but I think that might be limited to Dramatis Personæ, and even if not, creating a group of characters for one line seems like overkill.

My first thought was to be able to combine them, like this:

```
\alicespeaks \bobspeaks Three!
```

In the hopes that Dramatist would generate my expected outcome. But it doesn't seem to work that way; I get a blank line for Alice and then Bob says the line himself.

The other thing I thought of was to just create a temporary character with `\speaker`:

```
\speaker{ALICE and BOB} Three!
```

However, the approach seems kind of hacky because I'm creating a new character to represent two characters, and if I were to change their names in the `\Character`s at the top, it wouldn't get reflected here.

What is the recommended way to have two characters speak simultaneously?

### Full Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}
\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}

\begin{document}

\begin{drama}

\alicespeaks Are you ready?

\bobspeaks Yes. On three. One…two…

%How do I get them to say this?: Three!

\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How about `\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}
\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}
\Character{ALICE and BOB}{aliceandbob}
\begin{document}

\begin{drama}
\alicespeaks Are you ready?

\bobspeaks Yes. On three.

\aliceandbobspeaks  \direct{in unison} Three!
\end{drama} \end{document}`?

Comment: @marmot `! Undefined control sequence. l.15 \aliceandbobspeaks`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of `\speaker` is definitely the way to go since you need to refer to some entity that shouldn't appear in the *Dramatis Personae*, yet you're right that you shouldn't have to hardcode the names of the characters into the argument of `\speaker` in case you change the names to which `alice` and `bob` refer.

I see that the `dramatist` documentation says that `\Character` defines a new macro for use in stage directions named after the name of the character, e.g. `\alice` in the case of `\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}` and `\bob` in the case of `\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}`.  Perhaps you can use these macros within the argument to `\speaker`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}
\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}

\begin{document}

\begin{drama}

\alicespeaks Are you ready?

\bobspeaks Yes. On three. One…two…

\speaker{\alice and \bob} Three!

\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that `\speaker{\alice and \bob}` does work as intended, with the word `and` appearing slightly smaller than the characters' names when rendered in PDF.

Comment: I'll wait a bit before accepting just in case there are other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnseprule=0.4pt

\Character[ALICE]{ALICE}{alice}
\Character[BOB]{BOB}{bob}

\begin{document}

\begin{drama}

\alicespeaks Are you ready?

\bobspeaks Yes. On three. One…two…\strut% add space when missing descenders

\begin{paracol}{2}
\alicespeaks Wait!
\switchcolumn
\bobspeaks Three!\strut
\switchcolumn*% to align remarks
\end{paracol}

\end{drama}
\end{document}
```